# Oauth + SPA + API backend

Tags: api, oauth, jwt, single-page-application

I'm setting up a service which needs to authorize against an existing Gitlab as OAuth Provider.
The service is a SPA which gets served by a webpack dev server in dev mode and a nginx server in production mode.
I'm also setting up an external API which should handle the Database and make request to the given gitlab instance (for example pull repos).

My SPA is authorizing against the Gitlab OAuth with the implicit_grant flow and is getting an access token. Currently I pass the access_token after the redirect to my API backend and there I get the Gitlab userid and username via a request to the gitlab instance with the access_token. With these I generate a jwt and send it to the client (SPA) and save it there so I can authorize my API with this JWT.
How would I handle the initial access_token in my backend (cause I need the token to make gitlab calls)?
Currently I'm thinking about writing it to the user in the database and get the user everytime he makes a request (normal passport flow), so I also have the token. But what if the token gets invalid or expires?
Should I use an interceptor in the backend and if the token is invalid (gitlab would give me a 401) redirect the 401 to my client, let him get a new token and pass it back to the backend, generate a new JWT, send this again to the client and let him do the same request as original reuested(via interceptor, too)?
Or should I just redirect the 401 to my client, let him get a new token, let him post this token to for example /renewToken and save the token to the database and use the old JWT?

Hope someone can help me unserstand this flow.

Answer (score 0):

The [Credential Management API](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/credential-management/) should be what your looking for on the client. That will retrieve the id and access tokens to that you can compare access tokens with your server/ap and then validate the id token.

Haven't seen a Git example but there are Google and Facebook examples.

Answer (score 0):

You could let the user send the initial access token and your backend API will just act based on the initial access token. Seems to me that it is not necessary to produce another JWT token in this case.

Comment: Updated the answer based on the comment thanks.